# A click to start the countdown timer and a second one to Pause the timer in the same button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to click on (Start/Pause) Button in order start the coundown in the first click and the second click to pause it.It should be two options in the same button to start and pause the timer.

Here a descriptive image :

[image]

A created a separated button for start and pause the countdown but i want to make them in the same button.

Here my React Js code:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      secondsElapsed: 1800000 / 1000 //time in seconds
    };
  }

  getHours() {
    return ("0" + Math.floor(this.state.secondsElapsed / 3600)).slice(-2);
  }

  getMinutes() {
    return ("0" + Math.floor((this.state.secondsElapsed % 3600) / 60)).slice(
      -2
    );
  }

  getSeconds() {
    return ("0" + (this.state.secondsElapsed % 60)).slice(-2);
  }

  startTime() {
    var _this = this;
    this.countdown = setInterval(function() {
      _this.setState({ secondsElapsed: _this.state.secondsElapsed - 1 });
    }, 1000);
  }

  resetTime() {
    this.reset = this.setState({
      secondsElapsed: (this.state.secondsElapsed = 0)
    });
  }

  pauseTime() {
    clearInterval(this.countdown);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="timer-container">
          <div className="bloc-timer"> {this.getHours()}</div>
          <div className="bloc-timer"> :{this.getMinutes()}</div>
          <div className="bloc-timer"> :{this.getSeconds()}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.startTime()}>Start</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.pauseTime()}>Pause</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.resetTime()}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional state variable `isActive` that keeps track of if your timer is active or not and choose what function to call when clicking the button based on that.

**Example**

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
    secondsElapsed: 1800000 / 1000 //time in seconds
  };

  getHours() {
    return ("0" + Math.floor(this.state.secondsElapsed / 3600)).slice(-2);
  }

  getMinutes() {
    return ("0" + Math.floor((this.state.secondsElapsed % 3600) / 60)).slice(
      -2
    );
  }

  getSeconds() {
    return ("0" + (this.state.secondsElapsed % 60)).slice(-2);
  }

  startTime = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: true });
    
    this.countdown = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(({ secondsElapsed }) => ({
        secondsElapsed: secondsElapsed - 1
      }));
    }, 1000);
  };

  resetTime = () => {
    clearInterval(this.countdown);
    this.setState({
      secondsElapsed: 1800000 / 1000,
      isActive: false
    });
  };

  pauseTime = () => {
    clearInterval(this.countdown);
    this.setState({ isActive: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="timer-container">
          <span className="bloc-timer"> {this.getHours()}</span>
          <span className="bloc-timer"> :{this.getMinutes()}</span>
          <span className="bloc-timer"> :{this.getSeconds()}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={this.state.isActive ? this.pauseTime : this.startTime}
          >
            Start/Pause
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.resetTime}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: {this.state.isActive ? this.pauseTime : this.startTime} . As beginner developper, can you explain my in simple words

Comment: @hichembelfekih Sure! It's called the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), so e.g. `condition ? someExpression : someOtherExpression` will evaluate to `someExpression` if `condition` is truthy, and to `someOtherExpression` if it is not.

Comment: Thanks alot my friend. Yes, it did work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Boolean to check the state of your timer. And trigger timer start or stop depending on its value. Basically add another function to change the state, and call startTime if it hasn't been started, and pauseTime it if has been started.